# Using callbacks without creating leaks

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, callback

Using this simple piece of code

```
function get_data(callback)
{
    connection.query(`GET QUERY;`, function(error, row) {
        if(error) throw error;
        var data = row;
        ...
        ...
        return callback(data);
        //Never setting to null data
    });
}
```

and later on calling this function like:

```
function handle_data(){
    ...
    get_data(function(data){
        var some_variable = data;
        //do some stuff
        ...
        //I dont set some_variable to null here either.
    });
}
```

`connection` comes from `mysql` package.

So I was wondering if I am creating a memory leak since I never set to null the data in the first function.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: A memory leak hidden somehwere in my code and I cant find it. I used memwatch-next and confirmed there is somewhere, along with the google inspect but I cant seem to have pinpoint it yet. So as I have no closures (unless I missed something) I started checking what am not sure of.

Comment: Also I have one minor additional question, if inside a function I return another function in which I have variables declared, is that considered closure, and therefore I have to set them to null in order to eliminate potential memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory leak in your code. Array and Object variables are passed by 'copy of reference' in javascript, and it keeps pointing to the same object. As long as a valid reference is in the scope of the program, the object remains in memory, or else it is cleaned. For a primitive variable, it gets cleaned when it is no longer in scope.
However, if you are opening a mysql connection and not closing it, once it the job is done, it could lead to connection leakage.

Comment: I doubt there is a memory leak in my connection since I open one and keep it throughout the life of my process.

Comment: Also I noticed that by calling the GC multiple times (global.gc()), the memwatch-next tells me there is a memory leak while I changed nothing, and no on-going loop exists